# PostgreSQL cummulative sum max condition

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
account 
size   id    name 
100    1     John 
200    2     Mary 
300    3     Jane 
400    4     Anne
100    5     Mike 
600    6     Joanne
```

I want to partition the rows in groups, where the sum of size <= 600.

Expected result:

```
account 
group  size   id    name 
1       100    1     John 
1       200    2     Mary 
1       300    3     Jane 
2       400    4     Anne
2       100    5     Mike 
3       600    6     Joanne
```

I don't know how to do the partition and add the condition.

Comment: more simple  solution: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=26cd2ef3ef628f6bb7e8fd9757095c22

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of how to do this without recursion.  I left the `running_total` in the result to make it easier to follow:

```
with recursive rns as ( -- Assign row numbers as rn in case of gaps in id
  select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
    from account
), sumgrp as ( -- Start with first row
  select size, id, name, rn, 1 as grp, size as running_total
    from rns
   where rn = 1
  union all
  select n.size, n.id, n.name, n.rn, 
         case  -- Increment the grp when running_total exceeds 600
           when p.running_total + n.size > 600 then p.grp + 1 
           else p.grp 
         end as grp,
         case  -- Reset the running_total when it exceeds 600
           when p.running_total + n.size > 600 then n.size 
           else p.running_total + n.size 
         end as running_total
    from sumgrp p
         join rns n on n.rn = p.rn + 1
)
select grp, size, id, name, running_total
  from sumgrp 
 order by id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=475e42e47838a58304c08326744fb3c4)*